# How to call my public class to my main form?

Tags: c#, forms, function, class, methods

I have this class `ClassMainForm` and a form named `MainForm`. I made a method in my class, then inside of that is my codes like `quantity1.Show`. My question is, how do I call my function from class to my main form? I'd appreciate all your help.

ClassMainForm :

```
public void Visible()
{
    GroupInstruction.Hide(); // <<== how do i call my controls in my MainForm?

    quantity1.Show(); // <<== how do i call my controls in my MainForm?
}
```

Thanks Guys...

Comment: I think you call them exactly that way. If it's your class form you have them declared as fields in partial class file. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new instance of your class:

```
ClassMainForm cmf = new ClassMainForm();
```

After this you can use `cmf.NAMEOFYOURFUNCTION` to call your function.

```
NAMEOFYOURFUNCTION = One of the methods/functions in your class.
```

With the `cmf.` u refer to your class, and after the dot u select the name of your method/function.

EDIT:

Placed a numerupdown on the form, and I called it `numerUpDown1`.

**MAINFORM:**

```
namespace Stack_Overflow_2
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public NumericUpDown numericupdown()
        {
            return numericUpDown1;
        }
    }
}
```

CLASS:

```
namespace Stack_Overflow_2
{
    class ClassMainForm
    {
        MainForm mf = new MainForm();

        public void Visible()
        {
            mf.numericupdown().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks the code above. I already did it but my class does not recognize my quantity1.Show() which is a name of my numericupdown in my form. how do i do it?

Comment: What do you want to exactly do?

Comment: my controls are in design MainForm. i just want to put my codes e.g. = quantity1.Show(), to my class, but it has error. coz it does not know quantity1. do i need to put like MainForm.quantity1.Show()? or something?

Comment: Is the class where u are talking about, the class that is automatically generated for the form, or did you create a new class by yourself?

Comment: oh i just tried it, just now, and it did not work at all. Sir y451n how do I make all of my controls be hidden and shown? using the prob above? not just 1 control but many.

Comment: Why don't you use the self-generated class of the form?

Comment: I don't know how. How do I do self-generated class of the form sir?

Comment: Click on the triangle next to the name of the form in the solution explorer. Some files will popup downwards, inclusing the class that is generated for the form...